# Does room size affect how much damage deathclaws will do in a room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

It seems like with roughly equivalent dwellers in my first two rooms, the smaller room takes less damage.  It *seems* like they spend less time in smaller rooms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure with deathclaws since it's not easily repeatable, but for other hazards (Fire, Radroaches, Molerats) the smaller and less upgraded a room is the easier the hazard is to solve. I've tested this fairly extensively while doing the "Rush X rooms successfully", "Put out X fires" and "Solve X Incidents" objectives.

I have noticed deathclaws stay in my 3 wide room longer then the 2 wide room after it, but have not done any testing on different upgrade levels (both were max upgraded before Deathclaws started attacking me.) however based on other hazard durations I'd say chances are good having a series of Unupgraded Level 1 rooms w/ two badasses in each would be your best bet in dealing with deathclaws.

Comment: One thing I noticed, is that hazards seem to be easier to deal with, when your dwellers are well armed. In rooms where dwellers only have pistols, fires tend to take longer to subdue than in rooms where dwellers are equipped with shotguns, rifles, and laser weapons. Not sure if it's *because* of the weapons or just a coincidence, though.

Comment: High intelligence speeds fire extinguishers, high damage weapons (strength if unarmed) affects monster events... Though of course if you have low hp you might be before solving it making it harder for the other dwellers

Comment: Ah, so fire is affected by intelligence. Makes sense. The closer my rooms are to the Vault doors, the better the dwellers there are armed. Incidentally, my top most floors are the medbay and the science lab. There's the coincidence ;)

Comment: @aslum do you have sources for INT = fire?  I would like to see some data and train my dwellers likewise.  INT is currently my least trained stat.

Comment: @Nelson Extensive rushing. Using a small unupgraded room.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what I have noticed, take this as an answer or not, but in my situation Deathclaws seem to do the same amount of damage to everyone in the room.

I say that because, when deathclaws attack, I just let them go through my base and see how many die and how many escape.  Each room (1-3 room sizes with varying upgrades) generally has a full group, with a few rooms with less.  So with all those variables, the deathclaws never kill anyone that starts off with full health (or i get lucky?) even when they have crap armor or no armor.  They all go down to roughly 5-10% hp left, but they never die.  The only exception to this is any room they have to go through twice, because they will do the same amount of damage to those dwellers again.

Also, the help tells you they only show up when you open the Vault door, so if you want to test this out, make sure everyone is at full health with no rad poisoning, summon the deathclaws, and as long as they don't travel to a room more than once, check how many die.  If they do have a room they travel through twice, either move the dwellers out before they come back or move them before summoning the deathclaws.

Assuming the updates didn't change this, (2 updates have gone by) they seem to be used to cripple you more than kill you.  The dangerous ones are mole rats, especially when they spread (just my opinion at least).

Comment: They will definitely kill dwellers in a single pass if they've scaled up.  I think the common belief is that they scale based on the average level of all your dwellers.

Comment: @TomKerr people keep saying that, but it just isn't true. The average level in my vault is 50 (as in all 200 dwellers are level 50). Deathclaws never get close to killing anyone

Comment: Are these level 50 when their E was 1/2 or did they get to level 50 when their endurance is 10+7 at level 1?  The latter will have about 3 times more HP.

Comment: That's a good point about levels, but most of mine are low to mid levels (1-30~) and all of them end up with the same amount of health at the end of a raid.  The only time my dwellers die is when they don't have full health or they are in a room that gets hit twice.  The only thing different is the ones with 10 in 1 or more stats do more damage to the deathclaws

Comment: @Dallium  That doesn't actually support your position.  If everyone is 50 then they are all being attacked at a level that is balanced for them.  If my average is 45 and I have level 12 being attacked by DC, then the dweller are lower level than the DC that is balanced for the vault.

Comment: @TomKerr why would you put level 12s in a position to be attacked by deathclaws?

Comment: The point was to was to explain how the math works.  If lower levels can be killed 100-0 in a single pass, then the mechanic isn't just a percentage health.  To answer the question directly, I've had lower levels in early rooms when I was cycling out dwellers for training or leveling in the wastes.